# What does mean those kinds like "% U+R m" in hexadecimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, binaryfiles, hex-editors

I tried to read mkv video binary reading with python, so my code was:

```
a = open("vokoscreen-2019-12-21_12-15-11.mkv","rb")
a.read()
```

and got a big result, this is little bit part

```
W0I\xfb\xd4\x95l\xcfG\xa1\xa0\xb20\x9a\xb6\xa9\xbc\xa2\xdd\xc5\x9b}\x17e\xc2q\xa8d\x94\xda\x91\xd5F\xb9\xcbW2QK+p/\xc0\xd9\xf4D\x84\xda\xcb\xa7\xd42(b\r\x8f\x10\xb5\x84\xb0\x8f\xe3,\xaaf\xcfkd\xcf\xdb(}\xcf\tp\x84\xde\xb2l\xbfZ\xc8\xcc\x03+\xfe7;\x816\xa8sh] m\
```

my question is what is  ( } in xdb(} ?, what is this xcbW2QK+p ?, what is ] in this xa8sh] .
thanks .

Comment: Can I ask what you actually expected to get? A list of images? The script for that movie? Your title mentions hexadecimal – were you expecting that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python bytes literals display the printable ASCII character that corresponds to the byte's value if such a character exists, otherwise the escaped hex value is displayed.

For example:

```
>>> # Inside the ASCII range but unprintable
>>> b'\x01'
b'\x01'

>>> # Inside the ASCII range and printable
>>> b'\x36'
b'6'

>>> # Outside the ASCII range
>>> b'\x91'
b'\x91'
```

The [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) comments:

> [Bytes literals] may only contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater must be expressed with escapes.

Comment: Thank you, i understood that b'\x01\x59' gives me a result '\x01Y' becuase 0x01 is [Start heading] in ascii table so it is unprintable,  and 0x59 is Y in ascii table and it is printable .

Comment: Is there a way to get hex code without replacing by values from ascii ?